How can I use TARGET-FILE with org-babel-tangle-file?
No matter what I set TARGET-FILE to, it has no effect. Is this supposed to be a full path?
(org-babel-tangle-file FILE &optional TARGET-FILE LANG-RE)


As the doc string of the function states: "Optional argument TARGET-FILE can be used to specify a default export file for all source blocks" (emphasis added). IOW, that's where tangled code blocks will go if they don't specify another destination.
Try putting the following in /tmp/foo10.org:

* Tangle

#+begin_src elisp :tangle yes
  (setq x 3)
#+end_src

#+begin_src elisp
  (setq y 4)
#+end_src

#+begin_src elisp
  (setq z 5)
#+end_src


With /tmp as the current working directory, doing M-: (org-babel-tangle-file "foo10.org" "foo111.txt") returns ("/tmp/foo11.txt" "/tmp/foo10.el") and if you examine foo10.el, it contains:
(setq x 3)

because :tangle yes on the first code block specifies foo10.el as its output file (because :tangle yes uses the name of the Org mode file with the .org suffix replaced by a language specific suffix - .el in this case because it is an elisp source block).
If you examine foo11.txt, it contains:
(setq y 4)

(setq z 5)

because those code blocks don't specify an output file, so they get the default specified in the function call.
